# jackson scala xml unable to deserialize

Tags: scala, serialization, jackson, jackson-module-scala

I have the following code

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlSeeAlso(Array(classOf[EmailNotification],classOf[WebhookNotification]))
abstract class Notification {
}

@XmlRootElement
case class EmailNotification(@BeanProperty var recipients: JList[String],
                             @BeanProperty var subjectTemplate: String) extends Notification {
  def this() = this(new java.util.ArrayList[String](), null)
}
```

I am trying to deserialize the `notificationDetails` field from the following json to a list of Notification types.

```
        "notificationDetails":["recipients":["a@b.com"], "subjectTemplate": "hmmm"}],
```

I am getting the following error

`Caused by: org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of Notification, problem: abstract types can only be instantiated with additional type information
 at [Source: org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpInput@4afa6dff; line: 1, column: 281] (through reference chain: Monitor["monitorRules"]->MonitorRules["notificationDetails"])
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:163)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializationContext.instantiationException(StdDeserializationContext.java:233)
...`

Am i missing any annotations on my case classes?

Comment: Looks like you declare `notificationDetails` as a list of `Notification` instead of `EmailNotification`, and Jackson cannot deserialize it because  `Notification` is an abstract class.

Comment: Well I guess I am trying to implement inheritance via jackson. I want it to be able to parse an instance of `Notification` into the appropriate `EmailNotification` type( which extends notifcation). I think that is the purpose of the `@XMLSeeAlso` annotation.

Comment: I see. `@XMLSeeAlso` need to include `jackson-module-jaxb-annotations` for mapper. You may check [this unit test](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-jaxb-annotations/blob/948a0d5af4161836c0ac4870d7e1924e4c8326a8/src/test/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/module/jaxb/types/TestJaxbPolymorphic.java) for reference and see whether can help.